# Changing themes to 'Adwaita-dark' does not change the AppMenu color?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell

When installing 'gnome-tweaks' and changing the theme to 'Adwaita-dark' some colors remain from the original 'Ambiance' theme:

[image: Screenshot to display colors of Ambiance when using Adwaita-dark.]

Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install User Theme Extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/

Instruction [here](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/).

Now, Shell Style is changeable. Use Gnome Tweak -> Appearance -> Shell

Comment: First of all thank you! Once I've installed the 'gnome-shell-extensions' and visit Gnome Tweak -> Appearance -> Shell there are no options to select from just default?

Comment: @average_penguin You'll have to install some themes first. Please see the answer to my proposed duplicate question. There are links to some Adwaita-like themes for shell (Adwaita-slim, Minwaita ) you can use.

Comment: @pomsky, I appreciate the link and help. However, I'm wondering if you can point the "Shell" option in "Apperance" to the Adwaita-Dark theme already installed by default in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: @average_penguin In GNOME Tweaks > Appearance, under *Themes* you should find four entries: *Applications* (which is actually the GTK+ theme), *Cursor*, *Icons* and *Shell*. Your installed Adwaita-Dark theme probably doesn't contain a shell theme.

Comment: @pomsky, I wouldn't haven guessed that at all! Big thank you for the help to both of you!